# Why is the background of my buttons not changing

Tags: android, user-interface, colors, widget, styles

I'm trying to create a global style where my buttons have a dark grey background with white text. The text color is fine. I'm able to change it but for some reason the background color of the buttons wont change. What am I doing wrong.

Here is my colors xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#bf360c</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryLight">#f9683a</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#870000</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryText">#000000</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#a4a4a4</color>
    <color name="colorWindowBackground">#fafafa</color>

    <color name="RED">#ff0000</color>
    <color name="BLUE">#000fff</color>
    <color name="GREEN">#00FF00</color>
    <color name="YELLOW">#FFEB3B</color>
    <color name="DARK_GREY">#494949</color>
</resources>
```

Here is my styles xml:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimaryText</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorWindowBackground</item>
        <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/buttonColor</item>

    </style>

    <style name="buttonColor" parent="android:style/Widget.Button">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorWindowBackground</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/DARK_GREY</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

And why did my exit button shrink all of a sudden?
[image]

Now I have this but the exit button shrank??????

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    tools:context="com.checkinsystems.ez_score.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/match_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:onClick="goToMatchScreen"
        android:text="@string/match_button"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/competitors_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:onClick="goToCompetitorsScreen"
        android:text="@string/competitors_button"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/match_button"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/scores_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:onClick="goToScoresScreen"
        android:text="@string/scores_button"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/competitors_button"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/reports_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:onClick="goToReportsActivity"
        android:text="@string/reports_button"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/scores_button"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/exit_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/exit_button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you set the background of the buttons?

```
android:background=""
```

Comment: wow that was simple and it worked. You would think colorBackground, being an android attribute would have been the answer. Also, I'm going to post the new interface. Why would changing the color change the size of the button? makes no sense

Comment: @HelpMeI'mStupid You should put the xml of the button so we can see what is happening :)

Comment: Don't use wrap content for the width and height. That would make the button small.

Comment: see my second answer @HelpMeI'mStupid

Comment: @Abhi I know I can add padding or change the width and height. I guess I was just hoping to get some clue as to why it changed like that. Very strange. Thanks for the help everyone

Comment: @HelpMeI'mStupid as you have changed the style of the background of the button then android lost all the padding and size configurations that it had from the default. That is probably it :)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/yourColor</item>
```

Instead of

```
 <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/DARK_GREY</item>`.
```

Comment: I tried it but colorButtonNormal is API 21 and my min is 19. Changing it to background like joao86 suggested worked but now my exit button shrinks

Comment: Don't use wrap content for the width and height. That would make the button small.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding you second issue with the button exit, try changing the width and the height of the button from "wrap_content"

```
...
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
...
```